# How to send user to page after clicking print button

Tags: javascript, button, printing, onclick

```
<button type="button" onClick="window.location.href='http://mywebsite.com';window.print();return false;">Print</button>
```

Above works but I want to print first, then have a short delay and then send the user to the specified page.

I tried this without success:

```
<button type="button" onClick="setTimeout('window.location.href='http://mywebsite.com', 100);window.print();return false;">Print</button>
```

Comment: You have done some mistake to use of quote, view my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, this is the same code you have used, i have just edited it

```
<button type="button" onClick="setTimeout('window.location.href=\'http://www.google.com\'', 3000);window.print();return false;">Print</button>
```

this is worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

this code requires jquery  http://jquery.com/

Please note that setTimeout() is in milliseconds, and a delay of 100 ms will not be noticeable by the user.

```
<button type="button" id="print_button">Print</button>

<script>
$().ready(function() {
  $(document.getElementById('print_button')).click(function() {
    window.print()

    setTimeout(function() {
       window.location.href = 'http://mywebsite.com'
    }, 5000)

    return false
  })
})
</script>
```

Comment: So there is no way of doing this without using a function and inserting script tags? I'm restricted by a cms where I can add a HML-module in the middle of the page (I have no acces to the "real" code) but I don't think that adding a script-tag in the middle of the page would be the proper way of doing this.

Comment: I am sure this would work too, but in different circumstances where I could really access all files and maniplulate the code freely.